# Advantage of using MPI_PACK()

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, packing

I know that `MPI_PACK()` is used to bundle the non-contiguous data together and send them, but what is the use of it, rather then sending data using `MPI_Send()` one after the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that MPI_PACK() is used to bundle the non-contiguous data
> together and send them, but what is the use of it,

One of the advantages is precisely not having to

> then sending data using MPI_Send() one after the other?

You used to reduce the number of MPI calls across processes (which tend to be a parallelization bottleneck). Typically, the time that one saves by having fewer communication calls justifies the time taken on computing all the code related with the `MPI_PACK()` call.

From [Pack and unpack](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node62.htm) one can read some of the other benefits (*e.g.,* compatibility, flexibility and abstraction), namely:

> The pack/unpack routines are provided **for compatibility with previous libraries. **
> Also, they **provide some functionality that is not otherwise available
> in MPI.** For instance, a message can be received in several parts,
> where the receive operation done on a later part may depend on the
> content of a former part. Another use is that outgoing messages may be
> explicitly buffered in user supplied space, thus overriding the system
> buffering policy. Finally, the availability of pack and unpack
> operations **facilitates the development of additional communication
> libraries layered on top of MPI.**

This may not be the best analogy; very superficially you can think of it as for the same reason that one tries to pack as many items as possible in one box; to minimize the number of times that one has to carry that box, and consequently reducing the number of trips -- analogous to the communication.

Outside of the scope of this question but still [useful](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node62.htm) nonetheless:

> Derived datatypes, which are described in Section Derived datatypes ,
> allow one, in most cases, to avoid explicit packing and unpacking

for a better understand have a look at [Derived Datatypes vs Pack/Unpack](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node90.html)